# Use ~ (tilde) for bitwise invert

Tags: vim

What is a good way to extend the functionality of the <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) key in Vim to invert 1s and 0s in text in addition to toggling case?

That is to say, if my cursor is on a 0 or 1 in normal mode and I want <kbd>~</kbd> to transform it into a 1 or 0 (respectively), what is a good way to accomplish this without changing the normal behavior for alphabetic characters (uppercase/lowercase swap)?

Comment: http://code.google.com/searchframe#KJDzSCntchY/src/ops.c&q=op_tilde%20package:vim%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=2423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at `:help ~` says "no". You'll probably have to write a small function and map it to `~`:

```
function! BinSwitch()
  let current_char = getline(".")[col(".") - 1]
  if current_char == "0"
    normal! r1
  elseif current_char == "1"
    normal! r0
  else
    normal! ~
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap ~ :silent call BinSwitch()<cr>
```

Comment: You could also add a final `else` case to call `normal! ~`, and then map the function to `~` to provide the extended functionality.

Comment: I'd love to see this advance to the next character and work in visual mode. I may take the time to write this soon. :)

Comment: @EricBoehs did you ever do that? =]